# Mingw build - depends on DLL not native to windows

Tags: c++, build, shared-libraries, mingw

I'm compiling my library for export as a shared library using MinGW (GCC 4.5.0). I do this by compiling all the source files using MAKE commands similar to:

```
gcc -shared -c mysource.cpp -o mysource.o
```

And then finally:

```
gcc -shared -lstdc++ -lm -lws2_32 mysource.o -o mylib.dll
```

When I do a dependency walk of my output file (using http://www.dependencywalker.com/ for example), I see that there are 3 dependencies:

```
KERNEL32.dll
MSVCRT.dll
LIBSTDC++-6.DLL
```

Having my DLL depend on files that don't ship with windows is sub-optimal for my end goal.

Is there a way I can setup my system up so that the final output (DLL) **ONLY** depends on **KERNEL32** and **MSVCRT**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-static` flag may be what you're looking for. (It still looks funny to me to use both `-static` and `-shared` on the same line, but they are not opposites.)

If you would use `g++` as a driver instead of `gcc`, you could instead use the `-static-libstdc++` flag.

Comment: This worked. I build using the -shared option, and link the runtimes using the -static-libstdc++.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's exactly what you told your linker to do with `-lstdc++` ... perhaps move that parameter *before* the `-shared` and link again. To my knowledge that should use the static version of the C++ standard lib then.

Note: I think there was also a good reason to prefer g++ for C++ targets rather than using gcc. Probably it was about the inclusion of the C++ standard lib. Can't remember it from the top of my head. Also, I don't know whether MinGW differs in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct answer is "NO."  Other people answering this have not attempted to solve your issue.  I'd be delighted to be shown how I am wrong but I have exhaustively investigated this and at a minimum, both `MINGW` and `CYGWIN` environments seem to require distribution with a windows specific dynamic linked library (dll).

For Cygwin64 I compile using "g++" with these flags:

```
FFLAGS = -g -Wunused-variable -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

but the executable still requires distribution with `"cygwin1.dll"`  -- I very much agree this is sub-optimal and I don't understand the limitation.  I have found similar issues in `MINGW`.